# Exception thrown when using pre-generated views

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my project I have the following setup.

- EF6 installed
- Code first migration running
- Views pre-generated using Entity Framework Power Tools
- MVC project

This has been working fine up until now where after adding a new code first migration, and then regenerating the views, I can see the following error:

```
The current model no longer matches the model used to pre-generate the mapping views, as indicated by the fooClass.MappingHashValue property. 
Pre-generated mapping views must be either regenerated using the current model or removed if mapping views generated at runtime should be used instead. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=318050 for more information on Entity Framework mapping views.
```

There was no error generated at all when creating the migration, which is properly formed, and the database does manage to migrate perfectly well.  The exception arises when running the MVC site.

For completeness sake, the model change is as following:

```
public class MyClass
{  
    [Key]
    public int MyClassId
    //various other properties

    public int Version //newly added property
}
```

and the migration generated is:

```
public partial class AddingVersionNumber : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.MyClass", "Version", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.MyClass", "Version");
    }
}
```

Reverting back to the previous migration, removing the migration changes and then regenerating the views works perfectly fine as well.

I have also tried just adding in a random model change to see if it was anything wrong with the specific table I was changing, but this test change failed with the same error.  Seems that no matter how I change the model, the same error re-appears.

Another test I followed was to deleted the pre-generated views file from the project, but still the same exception is thrown.

Anyone else ever experienced anything similar?

Comment: I have just tried generating the views for a working DbContext (EF 6.1.2) and I get the same error. Weird.